# How to bind list<object> to a model and submit along with other form data?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-binding

This is what I'm trying to do:

I have a form with some input fields. Part of the form allows user to choose multiple options (Books) but will not know how many.

Model:

```
public class Data
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string age { get; set; }
    ...
    public List<Books> books { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

And,

```
public class Books
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Author { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
@model Applicants.Models.Data
...
<input type="text" name="Title" value="" />
<input type="text" name="Author" value="" />
```

My question is, **how do I submit multiple titles and authors along with other form data?** And how to properly name the input fields?

I have read this https://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/

But the example only submitted a List, not with other data.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using Razor view, you can use strongly-typed `@Html.TextBoxFor()` helpers and use `for` loop to generate multiple textboxes inside `books` list:

```
@model Applicants.Models.Data

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.name)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.age)

    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.books.Count; i++)
    {
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.books[i].Title)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.books[i].Author)
    }

    @* don't forget to add submit button here *@
}
```

The loop will produce `<input>` elements like this example below, assumed that you have POST action which has `Applicants.Models.Data` as viewmodel parameter:

```
<input name="books[0].Title" type="text" value="sometitle">
<input name="books[0].Author" type="text" value="somevalue">

<input name="books[1].Title" type="text" value="sometitle">
<input name="books[1].Author" type="text" value="somevalue">

<!-- other input elements depending on books list count -->
```

Refer to [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/IcspTw) for working example.

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this for bind model for normal html syntax its just example
 you need modified according to your need

```
<input type="text" name="Model.name" value="Curious George" />
<input type="text" name="Model.age" value="H.A. Rey" />

<input type="text" name="Model.books[0].Title" value="Curious George" />
<input type="text" name="Model.books[0].Author" value="H.A. Rey" />
```